# import * as fs from "fs"; in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

```
import * as fs from "fs";

const image1 = Media.addImage(document, fs.readFileSync("new.png"));
```

my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
  },
    "include": [
        "src/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I am using fs for add the image file in my word document using Docx, link: https://docx.js.org/#/usage/images

But I get the error while importing, please give me the solution.

Error: ERROR TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.readFileSync is not a function

Comment: Please also show your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Also, is this an application that you are running in a web browser or on a server? If you are running in a web browser, then your app will not have access to `fs`.

Comment: Further, what is the error message that you are seeing on import?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Thanks for the reply, I am working on Angular project to create a word Docx file, I need to import a image into the document. please help me to solve this one and use this link: https://docx.js.org/#/ for my reference

Comment: You need to share what the symptoms of your problem are. 'I get the error' is not sufficient

Comment: ERROR TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.readFileSync is not a function @Evert

Comment: Webpack suggests that you're trying to run this in a browser. `fs` cannot be used in browsers. You don't have access to the filesystem.

Comment: @Evert Please give me a alternate solution for import image into the word document

Comment: @M.vigneshraja the only way you can read a file from a user's system is with `<input type="file" />`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above you cannot access the file system directly, from the browser, using JavaScript for security.

The alternative, at least for what you are trying to do, is using the input of type "file" and read the content once the event is fired.

So that, in the HTML you would have:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

In the JS side you will have the onFileChanged method:

```
onFileChanged(event) {
   const file = event.target.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
    const result = e.target.result;
    // The content of result will depend on what method you invoke on
    // reader instance.
    console.log(e.target.result)
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
  // reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  // reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

You have to complete the implementation based on your needs... but this is what you need to be able to read a file content from file system.

For more information about this and the method in FileReader, you can go here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Comment: Thanks @Luis i am working on angular project i like to create a doc file. In that i need to import my image.